# Vue 3 TS / Webpack: Cannot find module '@/patterns/icon.vue' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, vue.js, symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I am working on a Symfony 5.4 Application together with Vue3 and TS using Webpack Encore.

My Project root structure looks like this:

```
app/
├─ assets/
│  ├─ controllers/
│  ├─ fonts/
│  ├─ styles/
│  ├─ vue/
│  │  ├─ components/
│  │  │  ├─ mega-menu.vue
│  │  ├─ patterns/
│  │  │  ├─ icon.vue
│  ├─ app.js
│  ├─ tsconfig.json
bin/
config/
node_modules/
public/
src/
templates/
var/
vendor/
webpack.config.js
```

I have a component called 'mega-menu.vue' that lays under vue/components/mega-menu.vue
I want to import an custom Icon component, which is under vue/patterns/icon.vue.

Regardless of what I change inside my Webpack or Tsconfig, I receive this error:

> ERROR in /Users/user/Projects/app/assets/vue/components/mega-menu.vue.ts(13,18)
> TS2307: Cannot find module '@/patterns/icon.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.

The strange thing is, importing it inside app.js the same wise does not give me an error . What is my issue? I added an '@' path alias for /assets/vue for both configurations.

I simply want to import child and parent components.

I have setup my Webpacke Encore like this:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
const glob = require('glob-all');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or subdirectory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')

    // enables the Symfony UX Stimulus bridge (used in assets/bootstrap.js)
    .enableStimulusBridge('./assets/controllers.json')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // configure Babel
    // .configureBabel((config) => {
    //     config.plugins.push('@babel/a-babel-plugin');
    // })

    // enables and configure @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = '3.23';
    })

    .enableVueLoader(() => {}, { runtimeCompilerBuild: false })
    .addPlugin(
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: false,
            __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: true,
        })
    )
    .addAliases({
        '@': path.resolve('assets/vue/'),
        vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
    })
    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    .enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    .enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment if you use postcss-loader
    .enablePostCssLoader()


    // uncomment if you use React
    //.enableReactPreset()

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    //.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    //.autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

**app.js**

```
/*
 * Welcome to your app's main JavaScript file!
 *
 * We recommend including the built version of this JavaScript file
 * (and its CSS file) in your base layout (base.html.twig).
 */

// any CSS you import will output into a single css file (app.css in this case)
import './styles/app.css';

// start the Stimulus application
import './bootstrap';

// import Vue dependencies
import {createApp} from "vue";

import Example from "@/components/Example.vue";
import MegaMenu from "@/components/mega-menu.vue";
import ImageList from "@/components/image-list.vue";
import MannequinHead from "@/components/mannequin-head.vue";
import FemaleHead from "@/patterns/mannequin/female-head.vue";
import Icon from "@/patterns/icon.vue";

const app = createApp({
    components: {
        Example,
        MegaMenu,
        ImageList,
        MannequinHead,
        FemaleHead,
        Icon
    }
});

app.mount('#app');
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./assets/vue/*"],
    },
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**components/mega-menu.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="mt-5 flex justify-center text-4xl">
    ...
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
//import Icon.vue from /patterns folder
import Icon from "@/patterns/icon.vue";
console.log('Hello, its the menu!');
</script>
```

**patterns/icon.vue**

```
<template>
  <component :is="icon" :size="size" :color="color" :stroke-width="strokeWidth" :default-class="defaultClass" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue';
import * as icons from "lucide-vue-next";

const props = defineProps({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  size: Number,
  color: String,
  strokeWidth: Number,
  defaultClass: String
})

const icon = computed(() => icons[props.name]);
</script>
```

Comment: Did you add a `shims-vue.d.ts` file?

Comment: I tried with no luck. Where I should place it and with which content?

Comment: You should place it next to your `app.js` file. The content should be the following: 

`declare module "*.vue" {
  import Vue from 'vue';
  export default Vue;
}`.

I was wondering, shouldn't your `app.js` be rewritten to a `.ts` file too? Maybe when that's a typescript file it will throw the same error when importing it there. But hopefully not after you've added the typescript declaration file.

Comment: Hey, little update.

I switched my setup using https://ux.symfony.com/.

I created the same directory structure as I had before, but in this approach I switched to the given 'controller logic', instead of regular JS to TS (main.js => main.ts).

BUT: I still had the issue as above, telling me missing imports (for files in the same directory. Creating a ```shims-vue.d.ts``` in the same directory (where my tsconfig.json lies) solved this issue.

Comment: Good to hear. I think best practices are to place the `.d.ts` file next to your `main.ts` but I guess it doesn't really matter.